# iPhone app issue getting result of equation to display on screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I'm trying to create an iphone app that does simple temperature conversion and when I run the code enter my number and hit submit nothing is displayed. I can't seem to find the problem here is my header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *convtype;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *inputtemp;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *submit;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputtemp;
@end
```

Basically I have a UISegmentedController to select which conversion to do (0 is c to f and 1 is f to c)

I have a text field inputtemp for the temperature to convert. Submit is the submit button and a UIlabel outputtemp is where I want the result to be displayed.

Not quite sure where this is going wrong here is the rest of my code in the .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize convtype;
@synthesize inputtemp;
@synthesize submit;
@synthesize outputtemp;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
inputtemp.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

...

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {

//defines input text
float temperature = [[inputtemp text] floatValue];
float sum = 0;

//selects formula based on convtype segment control
if (convtype.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    sum = (temperature * 9) / 5 + 32;
}
else if (convtype.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    sum = (temperature - 32) * 9 / 5; 
}

//outputs to screen
[outputtemp setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.2f", sum]];
}


@end
```

Is the problem with the setText? I'm not quite sure how to manipulate the ui label

Comment: You don't say what exactly is the problem. Try putting some NSLog statements into the code so you'll se what's going on. For example put: `NSLog (@"should set output: %3.2f", sum);` in front of `[outputtemp setText:...];` Though it looks like you forgot to connect corresponding UILabel from IB with it's IB outlet in code.

Comment: make sure you have connect all the IBOutlets in IB.

Comment: Log the value of sum and check if its not null.

Comment: I must have bigger problems. Sum is not coming up in console when I add it as a nslog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to connect all the IBOutlets as HChouhan02 said